# Android how to detect when app is paused and resumed

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to detect whether an Android app is currently active or not, and thought I could do this by listening for the `pause`and `resume` events of `Ti.App`. However, these events would never trigger when the app is pushed to background or brought to front.

I've tried to listen for the events like this:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', function(){
    Ti.API.log("resume event triggered");
});
Ti.App.addEventListener('pause', function(){
    Ti.API.log("paused event triggered");
});
```

These events is never called. After searching around I've figured that many other has had the same issue, but I couldn't find anything relevant for the latest versions of Appcelerator.

How should one do this "properly"?

Comment: just an another idea/way: you can set a boolean `isActivityActive` in all activitiy's `onResume()` and save them inside `sharedPreferences` . Then, you may use an `or` operator to detect if any activity is active. If you have an active activity, it means your app is running currently. Don't forget to set booleans to `false` in all activity's `onPause()` method.

Answer (score 4):

The events you listen to are iOS only.

Android activity's onPause and onResume might be helpful, if your app is only one activity.

Usually that's not the case. [This](http://www.tidev.io/2014/01/28/paused-resumed-events-on-android/) is the best solution I've found so far.

Comment: thumbs up for that post, for me the module "bencoding.android.tools" saved me, i strongly recommend it.

Comment: Yes, this is best solution. Works perfect for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an Android app that on activity's `onResume`, call a function. So I think that is a similar situation.

I used this code:

```
$.nameWin.addEventListener('open', function() {
    if (!$.nameWin.activityListenerLoaded) {
        var activity = $.nameWin.activity;
        ['resume'].forEach(function(e) {   
            activity.addEventListener(e, function() {
                //doSomething
            });
        });
       $.nameWin.activityListenerLoaded = true;
   }
});
```

In this way you can call a function or do something everytime your activity resume.

Let me know.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to the onPause / onResume events in the main 'activity'.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Activity

eg:

```
var main_activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
// var intent = main_activity.getIntent();
// var uri = intent.getData();

main_activity.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
    console.log('ANDROID APP PAUSED');
});
main_activity.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
    // uri = intent.getData();
    console.log('ANDROID APP RESUMED');
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Work from Titanium SDK 3.2.0:

```
Ti.Android.currentActivity.addEventListener('userleavehint', function(e){
    self.onAppPaused();
});
Ti.Android.currentActivity.addEventListener("newintent",function(){
    self.onAppResumed();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the `bencoding.android.tools` module for this for a long time.

I have now built and released and Hyperloop Module for this:

https://github.com/dieskim/Appcelerator.Hyperloop.appPauseResume

Cross-platform Hyperloop Module for detecting if app paused or resumed on both the iOS and Android

- iOS uses core T.App EventListeners pause and resume
- Android uses Narive Java Classes via Hyperloop and a setInterval to check and detect

Example:

```
// require appPauseResumeModule
var appPauseResume = require('appPauseResume');
// run appPauseResume and add resume and pause callbacks
appPauseResume({pause: function(){
                    Ti.API.info("appPauseResume - pause");
                },
                resume: function(){
                    Ti.API.info("appPauseResume - resume");
                },
                setIntervalTime: 1000,  // Optional - Default: 1000 miliseconds (1 second) 
});
```